# Edit start_date of a PayPal Agreement with Paypal-php-sdk

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am working with PayPal subscriptions and I have a problem trying to change the start_date of an Agreement.

Following the docs, the variable start_date can be updated (the API example shows an update of the start_date variable):

Update agreement:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/#agreement_update

I am using php sdk: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/billing/UpdateBillingAgreement.html

I update the agreement like:

```
$patch = new Patch();

$timestamp = strtotime("+5 minutes");
$startDate = date('c', $timestamp);
$updateValue = json_decode(
  '{
      "start_date": "' . $startDate . '"
   }'
);

$patch->setOp('replace')
    ->setPath('/')
    ->setValue($updateValue);
$patchRequest = new PatchRequest();
$patchRequest->addPatch($patch);

try {
    $agreement->update($patchRequest, $this->apiContext);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    log_message("ERROR", $ex);
}
```

The response of the PayPal request is 200 OK and everything seems to be ok, but when I retrieve the agreement, it is not updated at all.

The agreement is executed (state: Active). Can I update an Active agreement start_date?

Am I doing something wrong?

For more information, I have a Plan with a trial period and an infinite regular period. I create an agreement with this plan with a start_date of +1 week. I want to update the start_date because maybe I want to start the trial period now and not wait to the +1 week.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did u manage to resolve this?

Comment: Nope :( . I left the problem as a limitation with paypal accounts in my project :(